# sql query to append + or - and leading zeros

Tags: sql-server, database

trying to query a table that stores prices but need a way to append + if number is >1 and - if <1 and append  up to 8 zeros after the + or - sign , and round to 2 decimal places so if table contains

Current table:   prices
1000.3334

Expected return: prices
+00001000.33

Tried the following query but it does not round to 2 decimal places and does not add the + or - sign

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,prices),11) AS NUM FROM SALES;
```

Comment: Honestly, this is a job for the presentation layer.

Comment: What is the destination for the value/output? (Is it for an application? Excel sheet? Text output? API stream? Something else?)

Comment: What is the source data type? Separate from your actual issue, `CONVERT(VARCHAR` is dangerous, you should always give it the correct/max length!

Comment: `CASE WHEN prices > 1 THEN `+` ELSE `-` END + RIGHT('00000000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),ROUND(prices, 2)),11) ` should get you in the ballpark.

Comment: `FORMAT(prices, '+00000000.00;-00000000.00')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with others, yuck, this belongs in your front end / presentation layer:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN prices < 0 THEN '-' ELSE '+' END 
    + RIGHT(CONCAT(REPLICATE('0',9),
            ABS(CONVERT(decimal(11,2),prices))), 11)
  FROM dbo.sales;
```

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jHZR7Jyc).

Comment: This worked exactly how I need it. thanks!